# Twilio SMS Response - Python Quickstart Guide - 404 Not Found

Tags: python, http, flask, sms, twilio

Following the Twilio SMS Python Quickstart guide found here:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/quickstart/python

I can get up to the "Receive and reply to inbound SMS messages with Flask" section perfectly fine, with both my http://localhost:5000/ and ngrok URL showing the correct "Hello World" message.

However, as soon as I replace the run.py file code with the instructed code to reply to the sender with an sms, both URLs become dead with a "404 Not Found" error.

Have tried restarting everything etc.

run.py:

```
# /usr/bin/env python
# Download the twilio-python library from twilio.com/docs/libraries/python
from flask import Flask, request
from twilio.twiml.messaging_response import MessagingResponse

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/sms", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def sms_ahoy_reply():
    """Respond to incoming messages with a friendly SMS."""
    # Start our response
    resp = MessagingResponse()

    # Add a message
    resp.message("Ahoy! Thanks so much for your message.")

    return str(resp)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Any ideas?

As soon as I change the run.py code back to the original "Hello World" code both URLs run fine.

Also, the ngrok server does show an attempted connection when I send an sms message to the twilio number too, but with a "404 Not Found" message next to it.

Comment: have you tried `http://localhost:5000/sms` ?

Comment: Wow, it was that simple huh? Why they sneak in the /sms into the code without mentioning it saying to use the same links? Ugh. But perfect thank you!!